# Creating loop from user input

Tags: c

I wrote this code which works fine. However how do I create a loop where it will continue to ask the user for a new input and calculate its prime factorization until he enters 1 or less than 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x, i;
printf("Enter an integer:  ");
scanf("%d", &x);

 if (x <= 1)
{
    return 1;
}
printf("The prime factorization of %d is ", x);
if (x > 1)
{
    while (x%2 == 0) 
    { 
        printf("2 "); 
        x = x / 2; 
    } 
     for ( i = 3; i < 1009; i = i + 2)
    {
    while (x%i == 0) 
        { 
            printf("%d ",i); 
            x = x / i; 
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose everything in a `while` loop like the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x, i;
  while (1 == 1) {
    printf("Enter an integer:  ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x <= 1)
    {
      break;
    }
    printf("The prime factorization of %d is ", x);
    while (x%2 == 0) 
    { 
      printf("2 "); 
      x = x / 2; 
    } 
    for ( i = 3; i < 1009; i = i + 2)
    {
      while (x%i == 0) 
      { 
        printf("%d ",i); 
        x = x / i; 
      }
    }
    printf("\n");  //add extra line after each iteration
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `while(1)` or `for(;;)` instead of `while (1 == 1)`

Comment: He is clearely a beginner, so using that kind of loop might confuse him :)